# Excel VBA macro crashing when opening ADODB MS Access Recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado, adodb

I have a problem whereby I have an excel vba macro which works perfectly on my local machine however when stored on a server crashes.

I have identified the point at which the macro crashes, and this is when the excel macro attempts to open the ADODB Recordset (Db is MS Access).

The folder structure in the code is identical to my desktop setup so I don't think this is the issue. Just seems to be when the excel file attempts to query the database when opening the ADODB recordset.

Any help much appreciated! If you need further info please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, I have verified opening and closing both the connection and recordset as working fine.

Its when I pass this query through as the source which causes excel to crash. Here is my code:

```
Dim DirectoryLocation As String
DirectoryLocation = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim ConnString As String
ConnString = _
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DirectoryLocation & "\Data\UK Sales.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

'Declare new database connection object
Dim DBConn As ADODB.Connection
'Set new database connection object
Set DBConn = New ADODB.Connection

'Declare new recordset object
Dim SalesData As ADODB.Recordset
'Set new recordset object
Set SalesData = New ADODB.Recordset


'Define connection string property of database connection object
DBConn.ConnectionString = ConnString

'Open database connection
DBConn.Open
'On Error GoTo CloseConnection

'Set parameter values for reporting
Dim Rep_Param As String
Rep_Param = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C5"), Worksheets("Lookups").Range("H:I"), 2, 0)
Dim Rep_Option As String
Rep_Option = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("C6").Value

'Get customer names for report and populate report
'------------------------Query---------------------'
Dim Cust_Billing_Qry As String
Cust_Billing_Qry = "SELECT DISTINCT Customer_Billing FROM Sales WHERE " & Rep_Param & "='" & Rep_Option & "'"
SalesData.Open Cust_Billing_Qry, DBConn
'On Error GoTo CloseRecordSet
Sheets("Revenue Analysis (Detail)").Range("C:C").ClearContents
Sheets("Revenue Analysis (Detail)").Range("C6").CopyFromRecordset SalesData
SalesData.Close
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What type of server? Access should not run on external hard drives, non-Windows servers, internet folder clients (Dropbox, OneDrive, GoogleDrive), drives with low disk space, or thumb drives.

Comment: Hi, it's an external hard drive. I don't actually neeed to run the file, I just need my excel sheet to communicate with it? Stored on a shared server / network harddrive (ms) but running on local machine?

Comment: @parfait basically the database file sits on an external hard drive and I want the excel sheet to communicate with it, both files saved in same folder.

Comment: you can add an error handler, and write the error to a log file.

Comment: @Raj More I don't think this would work as there isn't an actual error, excel just crashes (not responding) and only way to resolve is to end process.